# Pandas: parse_csv throws "ValueError: Unable to parse string", when column starts with: "

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a tab-separated [file](https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.basics.tsv.gz) with pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

basics_cols_to_use = [
    'tconst', 'titleType', 'originalTitle', 'startYear', 'runtimeMinutes', 'genres'
]

chunk_gen = pd.read_csv(
        'reproduce.tsv',
        delimiter='\t',
        iterator=True,
        chunksize=10,
        na_values="\\N",
        usecols=basics_cols_to_use,
        dtype={
            'startYear': 'Int16',  # Int8 fails with NaN values :S
            'runtimeMinutes': 'Int16'
        },
        on_bad_lines="warn"
    )

for chunk in chunk_gen:
    pass
```

and I get the following exception:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib.pyx", line 2368, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric
ValueError: Unable to parse string "Reality-TV"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/proj/raw_data/tiskata.py", line 21, in <module>
    for chunk in chunk_gen:
  File "/home/user/.venv/imdbapi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1668, in __next__
    return self.get_chunk()
  File "/home/user/.venv/imdbapi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1777, in get_chunk
    return self.read(nrows=size)
  File "/home/user/.venv/imdbapi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py", line 1748, in read
    ) = self._engine.read(  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
  File "/home/user/.venv/imdbapi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers/c_parser_wrapper.py", line 234, in read
    chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "parsers.pyx", line 855, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "parsers.pyx", line 920, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "parsers.pyx", line 1065, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
  File "parsers.pyx", line 1104, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "parsers.pyx", line 1210, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "/home/user/.venv/imdbapi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/arrays/numeric.py", line 275, in _from_sequence_of_strings
    scalars = to_numeric(strings, errors="raise", dtype_backend="numpy_nullable")
  File "/home/user/.venv/imdbapi/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/numeric.py", line 222, in to_numeric
    values, new_mask = lib.maybe_convert_numeric(  # type: ignore[call-overload]  # noqa: E501
  File "lib.pyx", line 2410, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric
ValueError: Unable to parse string "Reality-TV" at position 1
```

(Ignore "Position 1" above. It refers to the number of line inside the chunk - `reproduce.tsv` has a header and two lines only)

By decreasing chunksize I managed to pinpoint one of the points where it happens:

```
tconst  titleType       primaryTitle    originalTitle   isAdult startYear       endYear runtimeMinutes  genres
tt10233360      tvEpisode       La venganza de Benjamín La venganza de Benjamín 0       2019    \N      \N      Crime,Drama,Thriller
tt10233364      tvEpisode       "Rolling in the Deep Dish       "Rolling in the Deep Dish       0       2019    \N      \N      Reality-TV
```

It seems when a column is starting with a double quote like `"Rolling in the Deep Dish` above, it throws that misleading error.

Is there a way to ignore such lines?

Thanks in advance

```
Python 3.10.12
pandas==2.1.0
```

PS: I can probably get rid of the quotation marks at the beginning with:

```
sed -i -e 's/\t"/\t/g' reproduce.tsv
```

but I would prefer to have a way to calm down pandas parser on any ValueError it encounters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quotes are used to quote text fields containing special characters. `read_csv` sees a quoted field that ends with a tab but *isn't* followed by a field separator.

If you're sure quoting isn't used in the file, you can disable it with `quoting=3` or `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` :

```
pd.read_csv(
        'reproduce.tsv',
        delimiter='\t',
        quoting=3,
        iterator=True,
        chunksize=10,
        na_values="\\N",
        usecols=basics_cols_to_use,
        dtype={
            'startYear': 'Int16',  
            'runtimeMinutes': 'Int16'
        },
        on_bad_lines="warn"
    )
```